# Converting varied schemaless JSON to normalized columns in (Postgre)SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Currently I'm using PostgreSQL for this problem, but I am open to switching.

I have a table with a few million rows in this kind of format:

```
id | type | col2 | col3 | ... | extra_properties
---+------+------+------+-----+------------------
   |      |      |      |     |
```

Extra properties is a jsonb column and I am given this data, I cannot ask for it to be normalised beforehand.

A user might want to select using a certain extra_property field, like maybe "vehicle_color". The problem is that each row might have what is really a vehicle_color property, but call it something else, like "my-vehicle-color", "color_of_vehicle", "vehicle colour", etc. I want to produce a view like this:

```
id | type | col2 | col3 | ... | vehicle_color 
---+------+------+------+-----+---------------
   |      |      |      |     |
```

There is in all cases a one-to-one mapping between the "type" text column and the structure of the "extra_properties". My current solution is to have another table with the aliases, like:

```
type | prop_name         | new_name
-----+-------------------+--------------
uk   | veh_colour        | vehicle_color
au   | my-vehicle-colour | vehicle_color
```

Then use a function that generates an SQL query with this in the form

```
SELECT id, type, col2, extra_properties->'veh_colour' AS vehicle_color FROM original_table WHERE type='uk'
UNION
SELECT id, type, col2, extra_properties->'my-vehicle-colour' AS vehicle_color FROM original_table WHERE type='au'
```

Then I use that to create a view. Problems I can't solve:

- Querying the view is very slow since the query is very big, I have a few hundred types each with a few dozen aliases, the query is thousands of times larger than the one I just wrote
- If I use a materialized view, refreshing it is slow, which is also due to the previous problem
- Regenerating the query (in case a new type is added, we need to add new new_names, there might be more columns in the query, etc) takes a while. This is less of an issue, since the aliases table won't change much.

Is this even the best way to do this? If there is a solution with features from MySQL, Oracle DB, or something else, I want to hear about it! Bear in mind I need to keep the original data around (in case someone wants to find the original extra_properties) and the original data is what is being updated!

Comment: Are you able to normalize the data?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, are you asking if I can convert the JSON into columns for each property? This is possible, but each type is likely to have dozens of unique names, so this would result in hundreds of columns (maybe thousands). I haven't used SQL much outside basic usage, so sorry if I've misinterpreted.

Comment: I mean is there anyway to clean the data __before__ it is in the db. For instance, can you classify fields and convert them to a standard field?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Sometimes someone will want to search by the original property name if they know the type they are searching for, other times people don't know which type they want, but they want to search globally. To support both use cases, as far as I can see, I need to keep the schemaless data in the database as well as the standardised data. There is no way for me to get the inserters of the data to insert it in a standardised way either, anyway.